# Order a report builder report by the parameters entered

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

So I have an SSRS report with one parameter and got a request to order the report by the exact order that the parameter/order numbers entered. Is there any way to sort the report this way?

For example, the parameters/order numbers entered in order: 5, 10, 1, 3, 2
I need the report to come out in that exact order

Table:

| Order Number | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | A |
| 10 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 2 | E |

Below is the query too, but I don't think this is anything I could do in sql server anyway.

```
SELECT c.customer_name AS [Customer]
, oh.order_no AS [Pick Ticket Number]
FROM orders oh
    INNER JOIN customer c ON oh.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE  oh.order_no IN (@orderno)
GROUP BY c.customer_name, oh.order_no
```

Comment: Doesn't it send a parameter with string like `5,10,1,3,2`? You could parse that into some sort of structure that has a sequence with it too. For example a string like `5-1,10-2,1-3...` and then split that into suitable lists... but that's quite ugly hack for ordering. Assuming you don't want to build dynamic sql.

Comment: What kind of parameter is it? A text box or a drop-down list of orders or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a drop down list of order numbers for the user to choose from, then I don't you can do this easily as there is no way to know which order they were clicked in.

If the users are just typing into a multivalue parameter and pressing enter between each entry then you can do it like this...

Add new new parameter to your report (this can be hidden) call it something like 'pOrderSort` and set the **Default Value** expression to be

```
=JOIN(Parameters!orderno.Value, ",")
```

This will create a string, something like `"5,10,1,3,2"`.

Now change your dataset query to this..

```
declare @Seq table(orderNum int, SortBy int IDENTITY(1,1))

INSERT INTO @Seq (orderNum)
    SELECT value from string_split(@pOrderSort, ',') 


SELECT c.customer_name AS [Customer]
        , oh.order_no AS [Pick Ticket Number]
        , s.SortBy
    FROM orders oh
    INNER JOIN customer c ON oh.customer_id = c.customer_id
    INNER JOIN @Seq s ON oh.order_no = s.orderNum
GROUP BY c.customer_name, oh.order_no
ORDER BY s.SortBy
```

All we are doing here is splitting the passed in parameter into rows and assigning a sequence number in the SortBy column.

Now all we do is join to this table and order by the `SortBy` column. There is no need for the `WHERE` clause as we are joining only to the order number we need.

You can use the SortBy column in the report design to order the rows as required.

Comment: Thank you Alan, this put me in the right direction, my only issue was that I cannot use string_split but I still followed the same logic. I'll post my code below in case if anyone who cannot use string_split comes across this in the future.

Comment: Answer was based on SQL Server 2016 or later which support `string_split()`. If you don't have the function available, it's well worth adding your own. There are lots of exmaples out there to copy or I can share the one we used to use back in our SQL Server 2008 days if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it without string_split() so below is the code to get around that, other than that I followed Alan's answer with creating a hidden parameter named @orderlist that is joined with the @orderno parameter

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)
SET @str = @orderlist

DECLARE @separator varchar(max)
SET @separator = ','

DECLARE @Splited TABLE(id int IDENTITY(1,1), item decimal(19,0))

SET @str = REPLACE(@str, @separator, '''),(''')
SET @str = 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES(''' + @str + ''')) AS V(A)' 

INSERT INTO @Splited
EXEC(@str)

SELECT c.customer_name AS [Customer]
, oh.order_no AS [Pick Ticket Number]

FROM oe_hdr oh
    INNER JOIN customer c ON oh.customer_id = c.customer_id
    INNER JOIN @Splited ot ON ot.item = oh.order_no

GROUP BY c.customer_name, op.pick_ticket_no, ot.id
ORDER BY ot.id ASC
```